# jQuery .ready() for several forms

Tags: jquery

folks! I saw jQuery for the first time! Please suggest. I have several forms with [select] elements.

```
<form action="/configuration.html" class="settings">
TEST_MODE:
<select name="value" class="value">
    <option value=null></option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="setting" value="TEST_MODE" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<form action="/configuration.html" class="settings">
USE_DNS:
<select name="value" class="value">
    <option value=null></option>
    <option value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="setting" value="USE_DNS" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

I'm just trying to fill select elements with values taken from server on load.

```
$(".settings").ready(function() {
    var $form = $(this),
        settingName = $form.find("input[name='setting']").val(),
        selectObject = $form.find("select[name='value']");
    var rnd = Math.random(100);
    $.get("/configuration.html=read", {"setting":settingName, "rnd":rnd})
        .done(function(data) {
            selectObject.val(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("No answer from server!");
        });
});
```

And I've a problem here. Code is performed only for first form. I see that in server's logs. What should be done to done the same thing for second form too? And how correctly bind to 'select' element in this part:

```
selectObject = $form.find("select[name='value']");
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `each()` `$( "select" ).each();`

Comment: It's better when your answers are not comments @EisaAdil! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `selectObject = $form.find("select[name='value']");`

You can not do it this way, because you are querying for multiple objects when using `$form.find`. If you do `console.log(selectObject)` you will be able to see the output from this selection in your console, and thus see why it won't work.

You would need to use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through all of them and update the values:

```
$(".settings select[name='value']").each(function() {
    $(this).val(data);
});
```

**Edit:** I'm not 100% sure that selector will work, you may need to play with it.

Comment: Thanks, @r3mus. I'll try in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that works for me:

```
$(".settings").each(function() {
    var settingName = $(this).find("input[name='setting']").val();
    var selectObject = $(this).find("select");
    var rnd = Math.random(100);
    $.get("/configuration/read", {"setting":settingName, "rnd":rnd})
        .done(function(data) {
            selectObject.find("[value='" + data + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("No answer from server!");
        });
});
```